# Disable scroll in body - ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a app where there is list which loading by scroll, and I have modal window, when I open window I still can load list, but this is error. How can I disable scroll in parent window (body) ? I know about overflow: hidden for body, but maybe there is special option in Ext.window.Window in order to disable scroll.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have same issue with all ui controls under modal dialog. You can add transparent div to feel all background and display modal dialog in front of this div. In this case all ui controls in the back of dialog will not be accessible for user.

Comment: Could you clarify what is meant "add transparent div" ?

Answer (score 0):

When initialising your Ext.window.Window you can add param `modal: true` which will add an overlay to the background which may prevent user scrolling. Otherwise it will be a manual process of setting overflow:hidden on the body when your window is shown.

Source: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.window.Window